# Select correct and incorrect XML nodes in two separate files

Tags: c#

Ok, I have to do the following IN C# ( C Sharp ), I am new to C Sharp programming.

I have got  the following ( see below )XML file. It is required from me to select using XPath all coreect nodes in a separate .txt file, and all incorrect nodes as well in a separate .txt file.

The correct nodes need to satisfy the following conditions in XPath:

```
ResourceCatalog/ Resource
ResourceCatalog / ResourceGroup / Resource
ResourceCatalog ........... ResourceGroup / Resource
```

This is the original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceCatalog>
  <Resource name ="Res1"></Resource>
  <Resource>
    <Name>Res3</Name>
  </Resource>
  <Service>
    <Resource name ="Res2"></Resource>
    <ResourceGroup name="Group2">
      <Resource name ="Res4"></Resource>
      <Resource>
        <Name>Res6</Name>
      </Resource>
    </ResourceGroup>
  </Service>
  <ResourceGroup name="Group1">
    <ResourceGroup name="Group12">
      <Service>
        <Resource name ="Res8"></Resource>
      </Service>
      <Resource name ="Res5"></Resource>
      <Resource>
        <Name>Res7</Name>
      </Resource>
    </ResourceGroup>
    <Resource name ="Res9"></Resource>
  </ResourceGroup> 
</ResourceCatalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but i hate to see an SO question i come across go unanswered and since it might benefit someone in the future - you could use an XPath like the following:

```
//Resource
```

This will select all nodes in the XML document with the name **Resource**, which seems to match the criteria outlined in your question.  The following is a non-optimal, non-generic approach to solving this problem (since it requires the inverse XPath to be manually generated), but will work:

```
private static void SortNodes(string xml)
{
    const string correctXPath = @"//Resource";
    const string incorrectXPath = @"//*[not(contains(name(), 'Resource'))]";

    var document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(xml);

    var correctNodes = document.SelectNodes(correctXPath);
    var incorrectNodes = document.SelectNodes(incorrectXPath);

    foreach (var node in correctNodes)
    {
        // Put into 'correct' txt file
    }

    foreach (var node in incorrectNodes)
    {
        // Put into 'incorrect' txt file
    }
}
```

If your XML file is large you may also be better off using an XmlTextReader, rather than loading the entire document into an XmlDocument structure.

However if i were going to solve this myself, i would use **XSLT** since all you want to do is transform XML to another text form.  Off-hand i don't know the XSLT to use though so you would need to do more research on that.  There are plenty of examples online and this is a fairly simple scenario.